# Confusion about how differences in potential make state kets rotate at different speeds

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interferometry

In Sakurai's book "Modern Quantum Mechanics" (2nd ed.) on page 133 he describes gravity-induced quantum interference.

A mono-energetic beam of neutrons is split in two and brought together again. One of the two beams is takes an on average higher path than the other beam. An interference pattern is observed.

They then give a heuristic explanation of the phase shift as follows

> This time the potential at level BD is higher than that at level AC my $mg l_2 \sin \delta$, which means the state ket associated with path BD "rotates faster".

I don't really understand this heuristic. I understand that state kets with a higher energy have their phase rotate faster $|\psi(t)\rangle = \exp(-i H t) |\psi(0)\rangle$, but looking at it semi-classically, don't both paths have the same energy? What is gained in potential energy for the upper path, is lost in kinetic energy.